# Chevrotain CST to string

Tags: javascript, parsing, chevrotain

How can I reconstruct the original text from a Chevrotain [`CstElement`](https://chevrotain.io/docs/guide/concrete_syntax_tree.html#structure) or `CstNode` object? (These objects represent a [concrete syntax tree](https://chevrotain.io/docs/guide/concrete_syntax_tree.html).)

The documentation suggests that this should be possible, as it says the following about differences between ASTs and CSTs:

> the **exact original** text can not always be re-constructed from the AST.

Comment: That can only be done if all the input is converted into tokens, which is usually not the case. Quite often, spaces and comments are discarded and will not show up in a CST. But if they are, you will need to traverse the CST using some sort of visitor and print/dump the original text back to get the original. https://chevrotain.io/docs/guide/concrete_syntax_tree.html#traversing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is a full answer to your question or that it works for all languages, but if you have access to the input and location-tracking on, you can do something like this:

```js
  function textFromCstNode(input, cstNode) {
    if (Array.isArray(cstNode)) cstNode = cstNode[0];
    return input.substring(
      cstNode.location.startOffset,
      cstNode.location.endOffset + 1
    );
  }
```